# Which is the Most Efficient Way to Run a Function on a Link Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have so many links in my webpage. About 25 links with an id="reply_x". About 20 links with id="quote_x" and some links with id="like_x". I have written different functions using JQuery for different group of links. One function will run when some one clicks on any link having reply_x id and the other will run on any link clicked having id quote_x. Now I want to make my webpage efficient. So what is the most efficient way to run these function.

I have used the following method.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reply_x').click(function() {
  // function statements
     });
});
```

Is it an efficient way?? If not Which is more efficient way to run the function.

Comment: what do you mean by efficient here...?? you obviously need to bind those click events when dom is ready.

Comment: [Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is more efficient and easier. Add a common class to all those reply links, then use `$(document.body).on('click', 'a.reply', function() { })`.

Comment: by using an id as a selector it will only select the first matching element to the given selector. To make this click function fire for all links of reply_x and quote_x add those values as classes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, IDs must be unique so there should be only *one* `reply_x` ID-attribute element, but I'll assume that `_x` is actually a number.  That would get tough on your fingers having to type all of those bindings, so you should probably give all of them a class instead: `reply`:

```
$(".reply").on('click', function () {})
```

This binds the event to all elements, so it may not be the most efficient.  If they are all wrapped in the same container, you could use:

```
$("#container").on('click', '.reply', function () {})
```

...which seems to be more efficient as long as `#container` is close to the `.reply` elements based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618435/are-there-advantages-or-disadvantages-to-binding-on-a-parent-element-versus-the/14618891#14618891)

Comment: Suppose I have .replay class. Then Where should I run tihs $("#container").on('click', '.reply', function () {}) function. I mean document.ready or window.onload or somewhere else?