# Need help fixing my jquery code

Tags: jquery

I am not sure what is wrong with my code right now. I have the jquery set to where `if (i == 0)` and you click the button then the buttons background turns blue and then the variable (i) is set to 1. Then I have an `else if` statement saying that `if (i == 1)` then turn the button back to grey. The problem is it isn't working. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**JQUERY**

```
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (i == 0) {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $(this).css({
            'background-color' : 'lightblue',
            'border' : '1px solid #5FA9CF'
            });
        });
        i = 1;
    }

    else if (i == 1) {
        $('button').click(function() {
            $(this).css({
            'background-color' : '#E0E0E0',
            'border' : '1px solid #CCC'
            });
        });
        i = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: ... move that `if`...`else` inside button click.. even better use `class` to manipulate the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the condition inside the click event :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        if (i == 0) {
            $(this).css({
                'background-color' : 'lightblue',
                'border' : '1px solid #5FA9CF'
            });
            i = 1;
        }

        else if (i == 1) {
            $(this).css({
                'background-color' : '#E0E0E0',
                'border' : '1px solid #CCC'
            });
            i = 0;
        }
    })
});
```

When you write what you want to happen, it make it clear.

When the DOM is ready (`$(document).ready()`),

You want to click and the button (`$('button).click()`)

and if the value is equal to 0 do somthing (`if(i == 0)`)

else if it's equal to another thing (`else if(i == 1)`).

Comment: @MatthewR.Miller even though i would use class aswell, the OP asked why his code wasnt working. This is the reason why and doesnt deserve a downvote since it answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're binding a single handler at document load -- "turn this button blue". The second handler never gets run.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').click(function() {
         if (i == 0) {

           $(this).css({
            'background-color' : 'lightblue',
            'border' : '1px solid #5FA9CF'
            });
         i = 1;
         } else {
            $(this).css({
            'background-color' : '#E0E0E0',
            'border' : '1px solid #CCC'
            });
         i = 0;
         }
        });
}
```

Comment: @MatthewR.Miller The asker didn't ask "what should I do", they asked, "why isn't my handler working?" This is why.

Answer (score 1):

You could move that `if`...`else` inside the button click, or even better use css to manipulate the styles like below.

**CSS:**

```
.btn-lightblue { 
    background-color : lightblue; 
    border : 1px solid #5FA9CF; 
}

.btn-def { 
     background-color : #E0E0E0; 
     border : 1px solid #CCC; 
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {        
       if ($(this).hasClass('btn-def') {
          $(this).addClass('btn-lightblue').removeClass('btn-def');            
       } else {
           $(this).addClass('btn-def').removeClass('btn-lightblue');
       }
     });
});
```

Comment: Javascript looks good other than using delegate() function, However your CSS has syntax errors.

Comment: .btn-lightblue { background-color: lightblue; border: 1px solid #5FA9CF; }
.btn-def {background-color: #E0E0E0; border: 1px solid #CCC; }

Comment: Still wrong, see above is correct. Run it through: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: CSS Fixed, but again with the new jQuery for your javascript, using delegate is much better for "live" events, per my answer below.

Comment: What do you mean my "live events"? Do you mean dynamic content getting added to DOM? I don't think OP mentioned anything about adding content dynamically, besides using direct binding is always better than delegates unless it is too many to write.

Comment: Isn't delegate superseded by on in jQ 1.7?

Comment: @Terry Yes it is, it was deprecated to make use of `.on` - a single function to handle all :)

Comment: @Vega Aye aye! And +1 for the unfair downvote. You totally didn't deserve that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() 
{

        $('button').click(function() 
        {
           if (i === 0)
           {
            $(this).css({
            'background-color' : 'lightblue',
            'border' : '1px solid #5FA9CF'
            });

            i = 1;
           }
          else
          {
            $(this).css({
            'background-color' : '#E0E0E0',
            'border' : '1px solid #CCC'
            });

            i = 0;
          }
        });            
});
```

Comment: @MatthewR.Miller You don't go around downvoting people's answer just because they approach styling differently than you do (inline vs classes). +1 for a solution that actually works.

Comment: I was just using the same approach as the OP so OP could see where his approach was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should make those styles classes in your css.

The you can use the .hasClass http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/ function instead of (i == 0)

You should also use delegate for this kind of things http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: If you're going with class, why not using `toggleClass()`?

Comment: That would work, I was trying to get him into the basics of jQuery and learn a little more about it. But it would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS:

```
.class1 {
     background-color: lightblue;
     border: 1px solid #5FA9CF;
}

.class2 {
     background-color: #E0E0E0;
     border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Your Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('body').delegate('button', 'click', function() {

          if ($(this).hasClass('class1')) {
               $(this).toggleClass('class1', 'class2');
          }
          else {
               $(this).toggleClass('class2', 'class1');
          }

     });
});
```

Comment: 2 notes on your code. Don't use delegated event if the elements is not dynamicly added, it is not performance wise. You code can be reduced to : `$('button').click(function(){$(this).toggleClass('class1 class2')})` but the `button` need the `class1`on page load.

Comment: `.delegate()` has been replaced (and improved) with `.on()`. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: You are correct... my bad for working in a project currently that we can't update yet.

Comment: @MatthewR.Miller Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/14618891/297641 before using delegates. There are cases when delegates are essential, but this isn't the one

Comment: I don't think I was being obsessed, and per my comment above I said .on was a better solution.

Comment: @MatthewR.Miller Sorry, I didn't mean that.. but delegates should be discreetly used when it is necessary not on performance aspect, but on the usage stand point. Also `delegates` are for older version and you should move to use `.on` in a specific syntax to work with dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code, what about this?

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
});
```

paired with this css

```
button{background-color:#E0E0E0;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC}
button.on{background-color:#5FA9CF;border:1px solid #5FA9CF}
```

I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/y9KML/

Comment: Yes the overall problem could be optimized. I was more or less solving his problem the way he was solving it, but making it work.

Comment: refactoring is not a choice. i just wanted it to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UhaQW/2/)

css

```
.btn-on {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border : 1px solid #5FA9CF;
}
.btn-off {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border : 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = $("button");
    btn.on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-on");
    });
});
```